# how to execute second method on same instance of thread after finishing first

Tags: c#, multithreading

Suppose I have a thread like

```
var th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Method1));
th.Start();
th.Join(); //// wait for Method1 to finish

//// how to execute the Method2 on same thread th?
```

I want to excute Method2 on same insatnce of thread when it finishes the method Method1.

How can I do that?

Comment: You are obviously waiting until `Method1` completes before continuing.  Do you then want to wait again until `Method2` completes or do you want your original code to continue executing in parallel with `Method2`?  If it's the former, do you want to execute any code on the original thread between `Method1` completing and `Method2` beginning?

Comment: I just want to execute the Method2 on same instance of thread which we have already `th` in example. Updated the description.

Comment: No, you don't JUST want to execute both methods on the same thread.  You do want to execute both methods on the same thread; that's a given.  The details will determine the solution though.  The three scenarios I mentioned all involve the two methods being executed on the same thread but the implementation will be different for all three.  I don't ask questions like this for my health.  Instead of wasting my time and yours, just answer the questions I asked and we can find a solution to your problem.

Comment: i want to continue the original code to continue executing in parallel with Method 2.

Comment: May be you just experimenting. But in real life it doesn't make sense. You either start thread `Method1` which Calls `Method2` and `Method3`, or just start a new thread. If the thread is finished, why ask it to do more work if you can start new thread?

Comment: I know that I can create a new Thread. my question is, Is it possible or not ?

Comment: I guess, the answer is NO - because before you start the thread, you set it up with the method it will execute in the constructor. But then, there is no way to set another method. Both of your methods must be executed on the first pass.

Comment: @T.S. Thanks. I also have not found something like that. But I am wondering how the ThreadPool internally does this?

Comment: But since you have `th.Join()`, there was no point in running the other methods in a different thread to begin with.  Just call them directly...

Comment: Please be more specific. It is not clear at all from your question what _exactly_ it is you want to happen. The answer from Sai Puli seems like a good option, and frankly is the only way to _guarantee_ the second method is run in the same thread with the first. But you didn't provide enough of a code example for anyone to actually know for sure that's what you want to do, and running any number of methods in a different thread while you just join in the current thread makes no sense, suggesting the rest of your question might not either.

Comment: The solution would be to use a `WaitHandle`.  You would write a third method that calls both `Method1` and `Method2` and that third method would be the entry point for your `Thread`.  After starting the `Thread` you would then wait on the `WaitHandle`.  In that new method, you would signal the `WaitHandle` in between the calls to `Method1` and `Method2`.  That way, the original thread will wait for `Method1` to complete and then continue in parallel with `Method2`.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var th = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
        {
            Method1();
            Method2();
        }

        ));
        th.Start();
        th.Join();
    }

    static void Method1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method 1");
    }

    static void Method2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Method 2");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Task Parallel Library you can use continuewith to line up tasks.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => action("alpha"))
        .ContinueWith(antecendent => action("beta")) 
        .ContinueWith(antecendent => action("gamma"));
```